# Using Visual Studio with LocalDB - Is there bloat involved?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, localdb

I've been googling this for a bit and can't seem to find any info.  I'm going to create my first VS app (using C#) with a local database (this will be a distributed app so there's no central server involved), and I'm wondering if there are any concerns I should look at.  Specifically:

1) Are there corruption issues I should know about, and how do I do my best to prevent them, and

2) Will this database be prone to bloat, and if so how do I minimize it?

Comment: 1) I think anything `disk-related` is prone to corruption.  2) Bloat?  Can you tell us more about what your app will do?  Thanks buddy

Comment: Well, I have 2 applications I want to do.  One will read files on the local HD and give information about them.  This one, every time it's used it will need to delete the information in the local table and write the current information in it.  This one I'm more concerned about bloat, since the table will constantly expand and shrink.  The other is an inventory database, which should mostly expand but may shring by a record or 2 here and there.  I'm using these as tools to help me learn how to write distributed apps.